# Tracker effectively stops system after upgrade to 18.10

Tags: gnome, ram, tracker

After upgrading form 18.04 to 18.10 tracker-extract uses all CPU and memory eventually crashing the system.

If I run tracker reset --hard once after boot. The problem does not arise.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what causes it, but here a quide on how to triage it: https://gist.github.com/vancluever/d34b41eb77e6d077887c Related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106386/tracker-extract-is-using-a-huge-amount-of-ram/1113617#1113617

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please edit your post to include the output of `dpkg -l tracker-extract` Thank you for helping us help you!